# PostgreSQL query to list all table names from all servers

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I have 13 servers in Pgadmin, and about 100 databases in each

[image]

i know what it possible fro psql `SELECT datname FROM pg_database;` but it need 13 times do that.

1. I want to export list of all server at all tables names on each. How it possible do that in one query? something like sp_MSForEachDB
2. How to get also list of databases which is in use, and check when was last access time on each  database, as need to delete not used databases?

Comment: A single query can only query Information about a single database.

Comment: You'll need a shell/batch script that first gets the list of databases, then connects to each and runs the query using `psql`